# Get Element By Id

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to use javascript to get an element from the page and the element is null.

Visualforce javascript:

```
var GHCity = document.getElementById('{!$Component.apForm.accountPlanEdit.globalAddress.globalHQCity}').innerText;
```

Here is the visual force element:

```
<apex:inputField id="globalHQCity" value="{!Account.Global_Headquarters_City__c}"/>
```

Here is the html element rendered that I am getting

```
<input id="j_id0:apForm:accountPlanEdit:globalAddress:globalHQCity" 
 maxlength="255"
 name="j_id0:apForm:accountPlanEdit:globalAddress:globalHQCity" 
 size="20" type="text" value="Caracas">
```

Comment: can you try var GHCity = document.getElementById('...').value; instead of innertext

Comment: were you able to get the value of inputfield, I see value="Caracas" hence suggested to use value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.value; instead of innertext`. I am tried with your code and it is working with `.value`.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:form id="apForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="accountPlanEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="globalAddress">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Name}" id="globalHQCity" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GHCity = document.getElementById('{!$Component.apForm.accountPlanEdit.globalAddress.globalHQCity}').value;
        alert(GHCity);
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

html output

```
<input id="j_id0:apForm:accountPlanEdit:globalAddress:globalHQCity" maxlength="255" name="j_id0:apForm:accountPlanEdit:globalAddress:globalHQCity" size="20" type="text" value="University of Arizona">
```

Answer (score 3):

you will need to provide a page Id here

```
<apex:page id="thepage">
 -----//your code

 //Change your JS code now

 var GHCity = document.getElementById('{!$Component.thepage.apForm.accountPlanEdit.globalAddress.globalHQCity}').value;
```

Comment: Additionally the element with that `Id` must have an `innerText` property. Because this is an `<input />` element, `.value` is the correct property to use to get the current value of the element.

Comment: @MarkPond agree with you .Editing this answer to include .value

Answer (score 0):

You can give your input field some class name(add style class)

```
<apex:inputField id="globalHQCity" styleclass="findclass" value="{!Account.Global_Headquarters_City__c}"/>
```

and then can get the element value easily

```
document.getElementsByClassName('findclass')[0].value
```

you can get your required value. and if you are familior with jquery or can use jquery then you can also try this approach

```
jQuery( 'input[id$=input]' ) //finds all elements with ID ending in input
```

here is a complete example for your help

```
<apex:page id="page">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
            <apex:inputText id="input" onfocus="foo();" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
    <!-- Uploaded jQuery as a static resource -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryUI_1_8_20, 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')}" />
    <script>
        function foo() {
            jQuery( 'input[id$=input]' ).val('Foo');
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: 'getElementsByClassName' is not cross-browser compatible. So, it fails in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You should give an ID to the page

```
<apex:page id="pageID">
```

Now you need to skip the colon(':') in the ID by double slash('\')
So, the code looks like

```
 var GHCity = document.getElementById('pageID\\:apForm\\:accountPlanEdit\\globalAddress\\globalHQCity').innerText;
```